# Redirect files on sub domain to root domain with wildcard

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all files on a subdomain to the same file on the root domain.

subdomain path = img.example.com/example-directory/file.jpg
Root domain path = example.com/wp-content/uploads/file.jpg

This needs to redirect all files in example-directory to the same file in uploads on the root domain.

This is the code I have that is not working at all:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    =img.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/example-directory/(.+)$
RewriteRule ^           https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Your rule looks ok. Put it at the top of your htaccess file so that your server can read it.

Comment: And what does "not working at all" actually mean? Do you get an error? A white page? A wrong redirection? Or does nothing happen at all? What does your http server's error log file contain for test requests? What does your browser's network console say about the responses to your test requests?

Comment: Not working means the original page is being served, and no redirect is happening. The rule is at the top of htaccess.

Comment: By "page", presumably you mean "image"? Is it possible you have a front-end proxy in front of your application server that is serving your static assets? (Not uncommon these days on many shared servers.) Please add the HTTP response headers for such a request to your question. In particular, check the `Server` HTTP response header and any headers that start `X-`.